# Customizer Color Control Not Working

Tags: theme-development, theme-customizer

I am currently developing a theme which provides more customization in Customizer. I am trying to add color control option and it is not working. This is my code.

```
/* Color Section */
    
    $wp_customize -> add_setting( 'navbar_color', array(
        'default' => '#45ace0',
    ) );

    $wp_customize -> add_control( new WP_Customize_Color_Control( $wp_customize, 'navbar_color', array(
            'label'     => __( 'Navbar Color', 'text_domain' ),
            'section'   => 'color_section',
            'settings'  => 'navbar_color',
        )
        
    ) );
    
    $wp_customize -> add_section( 'color_section', array(
        'title'     => __( 'Color Section', 'text_domain' ),
    ) );
```

I can't see anything wrong here. Without this customizer is working. But when i add this code, customizer is not loading without any PHP error. Also when i replace to WP_Customize_Color_Control to WP_Customize_Image_Control it working without any problem. This problem only happens with Color Control.

Also, I am getting following JS errors in the console.

[image]

any solution would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the reason. The reason was i enqueued JQuery to my options pages. When i remove JQuery enqueue everything is working fine. Thanks for all the replies.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your ID name to another one. Maybe is an ID already in use:

```
navbar_color
```

To:

```
my_navbar_color
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your needs :

Register Your Customizer setting , Add Below Code in your functions.php

```
function themename_customize_register($wp_customize){

$wp_customize->add_section('themename_color_scheme', array(
    'title'    => __('Color Scheme', 'themename'),
    'priority' => 120,
));

//  =============================
//  = Color Picker              =
//  =============================

$wp_customize->add_setting('themename_theme_options[navbar_color]', array(
    'default'           => '#000',
    'sanitize_callback' => 'sanitize_hex_color',
    'capability'        => 'edit_theme_options',
    'type'           => 'option',

));

$wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Color_Control($wp_customize, 'navbar_color', array(
    'label'    => __('Link Color', 'themename'),
    'section'  => 'themename_color_scheme',
    'settings' => 'themename_theme_options[navbar_color]',
)));


//  =============================
//  = Text Input                =
//  =============================
$wp_customize->add_setting('themename_theme_options[text_test]', array(
    'default'        => 'Custom Text!',
    'capability'     => 'edit_theme_options',
    'type'           => 'option',

));

$wp_customize->add_control('themename_text_test', array(
    'label'      => __('Text Test', 'themename'),
    'section'    => 'themename_color_scheme',
    'settings'   => 'themename_theme_options[text_test]',
));

//  =============================
//  = Image Upload              =
//  =============================
$wp_customize->add_setting('themename_theme_options[image_upload_test]', array(
    'default'           => 'image.jpg',
    'capability'        => 'edit_theme_options',
    'type'           => 'option',

));

$wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Image_Control($wp_customize, 'image_upload_test', array(
    'label'    => __('Image Upload Test', 'themename'),
    'section'  => 'themename_color_scheme',
    'settings' => 'themename_theme_options[image_upload_test]',
)));

//  =============================
//  = File Upload               =
//  =============================
$wp_customize->add_setting('themename_theme_options[upload_test]', array(
    'default'           => 'arse',
    'capability'        => 'edit_theme_options',
    'type'           => 'option',

));

$wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Upload_Control($wp_customize, 'upload_test', array(
    'label'    => __('Upload Test', 'themename'),
    'section'  => 'themename_color_scheme',
    'settings' => 'themename_theme_options[upload_test]',
)));

 }

add_action('customize_register', 'themename_customize_register');
```

Refer Link For Your Knowledge [Click](https://maddisondesigns.com/2017/05/the-wordpress-customizer-a-developers-guide-part-1)

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply and also the link you provided is very useful for me. However i am still having this problem. This problem only occurs when using WP_Customize_Color_Control. I can use WP_Customize_Media_Control and WP_Customize_Image_Control without any problem.  When using WP_Customize_Color_Control customizer loading infinitely. I think it because of JS error i have provided above. But i can't figure it out.

Comment: My code is Modify check and Add New Setting for image upload & file upload On your functions.php

Comment: I think you have misunderstood my question. My problem is not with how to add image control or file control. I have no issue about using them. My problem is only when i use Wp_Customize_Color_Control customizer is not loading because of that Javascript error. There are lot of Javascript errors when using WP_Customize_Color_Control and i have provided them with an image above.